# Running a command in python script and storing the result in a csv file or as tuple

Tags: python, csv, subprocess

I'm trying to run OpenStack APIs from a python script. I used subprocess module to do that.

```
output = subprocess.check_output('nova-manage vm list',shell=True,)
print output
```

"nova-manage vm list" gives a table that has columns as "instance, node, type, state, launched, image, kernel, ramdisk, project, user, zone, index.

```
instance   node            type       state      launched                   image     kernel    ramdisk    project    user       zone       index
ubuntu12_1 compute1        m1.small   active     2014-03-25 07:57:51        946fbcc5-03c3-48a1-9ef9-f6d6362c6152                     53963e60e44c4c54b7507e81cf11ef2c f47f5c0a54374a4b8aa78e5349246b0f None       0
ubuntu12_2 compute1        m1.small   active     2014-03-25 07:59:03        946fbcc5-03c3-48a1-9ef9-f6d6362c6152                     53963e60e44c4c54b7507e81cf11ef2c f47f5c0a54374a4b8aa78e5349246b0f None       0
ubuntu12_3 compute2        m1.small   active     2014-03-26 07:27:16        946fbcc5-03c3-48a1-9ef9-f6d6362c6152                     53963e60e44c4c54b7507e81cf11ef2c f47f5c0a54374a4b8aa78e5349246b0f None       0
ubuntu12_4 compute2        m1.small   active     2014-03-26 07:46:56        946fbcc5-03c3-48a1-9ef9-f6d6362c6152                     53963e60e44c4c54b7507e81cf11ef2c f47f5c0a54374a4b8aa78e5349246b0f nova
```

Above is a sample example of output of running "nova-manage vm list" command.

I need to check only the first 4 columns of the output. How should I get only the first 4 columns out of the complete table? How should I store the value of these 4 columns in a csv file and access it?.

I'm a beginner in python scripting and have very little knowledge so please shed some light on my question.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you provide more details regarding the output? How does it look like? There might be two other options as well: Use the [OpenStack-API bindings](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-openstack-pythonapis/index.html?ca=drs-) directly (avoids the subprocess stuff) or process the "nova-manage" output with sed (or other unix-command line tools)

Comment: Thanks dorvak, the link you have provided is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is to use OpenStack API Python bindings directly as [@dorvak suggested in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765334/running-a-command-in-python-script-and-storing-the-result-in-a-csv-file-or-as-tu#comment34706355_22765334).

If you want to use a subprocess then you could use `str.split()` to parse output from `nova-manage` and [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write the first four columns to a csv file:

```
import csv
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

file = sys.stdout # or use with open('output_filename', 'wb') as file:
p = Popen(['nova-manage', 'vm', 'list'], stdout=PIPE)
next(p.stdout) # skip header line
csv.writer(file).writerows(line.split()[:4] for line in p.stdout)
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for the answer. I feel its good to use the OpenStack-API Bindings so that it'll be helpful to write other scripts related to OpenStack in future.
But the above script you have provided still prints all the columns of table instead of first four. What changes should I make?

Comment: @Veena: The code expects that `nova-manage` prints comma separated fields, one row per line. If it is not so; provide the output from `nova-manage` command. Don't put it in the comments, [update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22765334/edit)

Comment: @Veena: I've updated the answer to accept space-separated input produced by  `nova-manage`.